# How do you configuring Azure VMs with .NET 5.0 from the command line?

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface, virtual-machine

I'm setting up some virtual machines to run my service.  There may be several, so I'm trying to automate the process.  I've got a PowerShell script that successfully build the virtual machine, but now I want to install the dependent software that my .NET Core Web Application requires in the same script.

The first dependency I want to install is .NET 5.0 Runtime.  I've done this many times from the browser, but now I want to commit this to a script that runs after the VM has been built.

Comment: Use [dotnet-install scripts](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/scripts)

Comment: @amit_g - eh, I got the gist of that.  I'm looking for the general idea of how I get that script on a target machine, then invoke it.  I'm most of the way through an **Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand** based script now.  The dotnet-install scripts seem to be one of the key ingredients, though.  Thanks.

Comment: I believe it's also possible to create one image by whatever means (i.e. manualy) then take that as an image to create new VM's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource

Answer (score 1):

Test locally or on a test VM by installing using the [dotnet-install-script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script) and finalize the parameters. Then use [Set-AzVMExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmextension?view=azps-5.4.0) to install that script using custom script extension. The code would look like this (not tested)

```
$Command = "&powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; &([scriptblock]::Create((Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing 'https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1'))) <additional install-script args>"
$Settings = @{"commandToExecute" = "Powershell $Command";};

Set-AzVMExtension `
    -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" `
    -Location "Location" `
    -VMName "VirtualMachineName" `
    -Name "ExtensionName" `
    -Publisher "Contoso.Compute" `
    -Type "CustomScriptExtension" `
    -TypeHandlerVersion "1.1" `
    -Settings $Settings
```

Full details and schema of settings [custom-script-windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows)

You can also use [Set-AzureVMCustomScriptExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmcustomscriptextension?view=azps-5.4.0) for running custom scripts.

Answer (score 0):

As @amit_g recommended, you can use [Azure VM run command functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command) to run [install .net with scripts by PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net50#install-with-powershell-automation) directly to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work pretty well:

```
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName "$resourceGroupName" -Name "$machineName" -CommandId "RunPowerShellScript" -ScriptPath "configureMachine.ps1" -Parameter @{"machineName" = "$machineName"}
```

The contents of the Powershell script look something like this:

```
# The name of the VM is passed in as the first parameter.
param ($machineName)
if ($machineName -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "Usage: configureMachine -machineName <machineName>";
    Exit;
}

# Download the agent installation files.
$agentZip="agent.zip";
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.181.1/vsts-agent-win-x64-2.181.1.zip" -OutFile $agentZip

# Unpack them.
$agentDirectory="$env:SystemDrive\azagent";
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($agentZip, $agentDirectory);

# Configure the machine to work as a DevOps Agent.
&"$agentDirectory\config.cmd" --unattended --deploymentgroup --deploymentgroupname "Production" --agent "$machineName" --runasservice --work "_work" --url "https://dev.azure.com/theta-rex/" --projectname "openbook" --auth PAT --token te64yuv36tina2rvc2lsvwcsvctpwomiewz5fxihcubbdzaasoka

# Remove the Agent Zip files when installation is complete.
Remove-Item $agentZip;

# Download and install .NET 5.0
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1" -OutFile "dotnet-install.ps1"
&"./dotnet-install.ps1" -Channel 5.0 -Runtime aspnetcore -InstallDir "C:\Program Files\dotnet"
```

The end result is a machine configured to participate in Azure DevOps and ASP.NET 5.0.